# Spring security SAML2 working with more than one idp

Tags: java, spring-security, saml-2.0

I've followed [spring security](http://projects.spring.io/spring-security-saml/)
quick start and the sample application,
and managed to do make full  integration with one IDP (ssoCircle). is it possible to configure the securityContext.xml to support  more then one IDP and configure the Spring filter/router to use a different IDP by making couple of different paths ?

For example:

- myhost:8080/idpOne -> will follow the first IDP
- myhost:8080/idpTwo -> will follow the second IDP

Answer (score 0):

You can pass IDP's as list in the security-context*.xml:

The Github project for Spring Security SAML has an [example](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-saml/blob/master/sample/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/securityContext.xml)

Also the [documentation](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-security-saml/1.0.2.RELEASE/reference/pdf/spring-security-saml-reference.pdf) explains this within the **Extended metadata** section

Comment: my question is more about the routing, how can i route from one idp or a second idp by configuring the XML ?

Comment: In the idp discovery page, you choose which idp you want to follow. So you do not need to implement sub-paths for different idps yourself.